# Как правильно делать асинхронные POST запросы C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, post

делаю:

```
protected void Main(){
   List<customers> list = customers.ToList();
   foreach(customers item in list){
     new Thread(() => {
        SendPost(item.host);
     }).Start();
   }
}

private void SendPost(strirng host){
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(host);
   webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
   webRequest.Method = "POST";
   webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   ... 
}
```

вроде должно делаться все асинхронно, но по факту обрабатывается все не асинхронно.
если хост не отвечает, остальные не отправляются пока первый не отвалится

Comment: многопоточность != асинхронность

Comment: [HttpClient.PostAsync Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.8)